# Im unable to get databind mutiple selected values from Listbox in C#

Tags: c#

I'm not getting the multiple selected values. Can you please me with this?

Thank you in advance

.aspx markup:

.cs code:

```
foreach (ListItem item in lblMultiSelect.Items)
{
    if (item.Selected == true)
    {
        message += item.Text + " " + item.Value + "\\n";
    }
}

ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + message + "');", true);
```

Comment: Show us the code of your `.aspx` page please.

Comment: Please edit it into the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 string message = "";
            foreach (ListItem item in ListBox1.Items)
            {
                if (item.Selected == true)
                {
                    message += item.Text + " " + item.Value + "\\n";
                }
            }
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + message + "');", true);
```

This code worked for me

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple"><asp:ListItem Value="1">Hii</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem Value="2">I</asp:ListItem></asp:ListBox>
```

This was my design.I'll just suggest you to first use static values in listbox to see if that works

Comment: Yes , if i use the static values . even it works for me . But when i do data bind ,  i m not getting the values in C# .So please help me on this .

Comment: SqlDataAdapter myCommand = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    myCommand.Fill(ds, "MasterDataOI");


                    lblMultiSelect.DataSource = ds;
                    lblMultiSelect.DataTextField = "GroupName";
                    lblMultiSelect.DataValueField = "GroupName";
                    lblMultiSelect.DataBind();

Comment: string query = "select GroupName from MasterDataOI where CC='BBAN700652'";

Comment: .aspx code                                                                                        
  <asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="lblMultiSelect" SelectionMode="multiple" >
                                 <asp:ListItem />
                         
                             </asp:ListBox>

Comment: Please , can anyone update on this . Thank you in advance